# Laravel validation using class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use Laravel validation : [as described here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)

I am not going to place entire rule class, as it is straight from artisan make:rule.

PROBLEM:

When I try to test 'false' here:

```
function passes($attribute, $value)
{
   return false; //testing 'false' logs me out
}
```

This is how I use it in controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'image_64' => ['required', new \App\Rules\Base64Rule]
]);
```

It is like redirect isn't going to form page, but index page - which in my case logs user out (among other things).

Is there any protected var to mark proper redirect route, when method 'passes' returns false?

Anyone came across something like this?

**EDIT**

Sam,

As I mentioned, rule class is pristine - freshly generated:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Base64Rule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

If I run on top of my controller anything like:

```
use App\Rules\Base64Rule;

$rule = new Base64Rule;
dd($rule->passes('image_64', 'udfshjbfisuusoshgosghosh'));
```

I get whatever I have in rule's method passes().

If I use in rule's method passes() return true; it works right.

If I use in rule's method passes() dd('some'), I get 'some' in that controller test.

When test is 'false' and regular validation code is used:

```
use App\Rules\Base64Rule;

$this->validate($request, [
    'image_64' => ['required', new Base64Rule]
]);
```

... I get redirected to index page.

I have to follow request/response and see, where Laravel fails and why ... I guess. And is it my code, or a bug.

Comment: If Validation fails then a [`ValidationException`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php) is thrown, which is caught by the [`Handler`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php) and the Handler redirects the user to the previous page with the form input and errors ([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L241)). Do you have any redirects in your application that might be causing the default behaviour to not function?

Comment: Isn't the same 'validation fail' process being used when this is used: $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required|min:2|max:128']). Because this works perfect. Problem is only when I try a custom validation rule class. As to redirects - not really. Index page logs user out, as there are more than one password protected areas: admin and customer. System has no unprotected pages (accessible without login). But no interference you mentioned. It bugs me. I have to nail this *** ;)

Comment: I guess then that perhaps the issue is that there's an issue loading your rule and for whatever reason the exception is causing a redirect. What happens if you try `new \App\Rules\Base64Rule` outside of the validation? e.g: first line of your controller, do `$rule = new \App\Rules\Base64Rule;`. If this doesn't help track down the issue then please post the full code to your Base64Rule.

Comment: It is my code - I just installed clean Laravel 5.6 and it works well. There is $redirectTo in ValidationException, which could help, but I cannot seem to override it correctly.

Comment: You can update your question here to include your applications code and we can try and identify the issue and resolve it, rather than trying to work around it (which is a bad idea).

Comment: I'll do so, but first I have to identify this problem a bit in depth, since this is this system specific issue and posting whole system is not the way :) All I knot now, is that this system is allergic to Laravel exception. I have to find out why first. Thank you sam.

Comment: OK. I think I got it. Problem was not with framework - I checked on fresh install. System code I work with was good as well. Problem was with sheer content of $request, as one of inputs was base64 encoded, cropped image. Beast had on average just under 1KK chars. As a result, exception handler invalid() method was flipping and messing with redirect(), which malfunctioned and redirected to index. When I disabled withInput() all worked well. Bottom line, I will not be able to use Validator to validate base64 image. No matter. There are other ways. Sam - thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to identify it! :)